# Foundation 6 js gulp setup Can't find variable: define and require

Tags: jquery, gulp, zurb-foundation, babeljs

I am getting this error

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define from Modernizr

and

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require from Foundation.js

This is the first time I use Foundation 6 sass and I don't know what is causing the error.

The sass is working but js is not

## Is the info enough or is something else needed

This is my setup

## bower.json

```
  "devDependencies": {

    "foundation-sites": "^6.4.3",

    "motion-ui": "^1.2.3",

    "modernizr": "^3.5.0"

  }
```

## package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {

    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",

    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",

    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",

    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",

    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",

    "gulp": "^3.9.1",

    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",

    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",

    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",

    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",

    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.3",

    "webpack": "^3.10.0"

  }
```

## gulpfile.js

```
var pM_folder = './bower_components';



var gulp = require('gulp');

var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var babel = require("gulp-babel");

var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

require("babel-polyfill");



gulp.task('styles',function(){

  return gulp.src([

    './assets/styles/app.scss'

  ])

  .pipe(sass({

    includePaths: [

      pM_folder+'/foundation-sites/scss',

      pM_folder+'/motion-ui/src'

    ]

  }))

  .pipe(concat('app.css'))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))

  .pipe(livereload())

});



gulp.task('scripts', function () {

  gulp.src([

    pM_folder+'/jquery/dist/jquery.js',

    pM_folder+'/foundation-sites/js/entries/foundation.js',

    // pM_folder+'/foundation-sites/js/foundation/foundation.alert.js',

    './assets/scripts/app.js'

  ])

  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())

  .pipe(babel())

  .pipe(concat('app.js'))

  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))



  return gulp.src([pM_folder+'/modernizr/src/Modernizr.js'])

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));



});



gulp.task('html', function() {

    return gulp.src('./public/')

        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))

        .pipe(livereload())

});



    gulp.task('watch',function(){

      livereload.listen();

      gulp.watch('./assets/styles/**/*.scss',['styles']);

      gulp.watch('./public/**/*.*', ['html']);

      gulp.watch('./app/**/*.php', ['html']);

    });



gulp.task('default',['styles','scripts']);
```

---

If you use Foundation with a build system, you'll need to compile our code to ES5

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html

## .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .pipe(babel({
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }))
```